# POI slow when writing to existing xlsx file with sheet.shiftRow()

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hello I'm using Apache POI 3.11

I tried to write data of about 50,000 rows into an existing xlsx file. I got a slow performance (about 3 minutes). So I decided to use SSPerformanceTest as stated here https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10165

```
I discovered that the slowness is from calling sheet.createRow(); after sheet.shiftRow();
```

When I test SSPerformanceTest out of the box, it perform really good (50,000 rows for about 10 seconds) but after a little modification to suit my requirement, it went very bad.

I need the shiftRow because excel file will contains things at the bottom of the files like signature etc.

The code that is fine is here (with some debug to log time elapsed)

```
private static void addContent(Workbook workBook, boolean isHType, int rows, int cols) {
    Map<String, CellStyle> styles = createStyles(workBook);

    Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);


    long startShiftRow = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long endShiftRow = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("###@@@ Elapsed shift rows " + (endShiftRow - startShiftRow) + " milli seconds");

    Cell headerCell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
    headerCell.setCellValue("Header text is spanned across multiple cells");
    headerCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("header"));
    sheet.addMergedRegion(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("$A$1:$F$1"));

    int sheetNo = 0;
    int rowIndexInSheet = 1;
    double value = 0;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    double totalCreateRowTime = 0;
    double totalSetValue = 0;
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++) {
        if (isHType && sheetNo != rowIndex / 0x10000) {
            sheet = workBook.createSheet("Spillover from sheet " + (++sheetNo));
            headerCell.setCellValue("Header text is spanned across multiple cells");
            headerCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("header"));
            sheet.addMergedRegion(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("$A$1:$F$1"));
            rowIndexInSheet = 1;
        }
        long startCreateRow = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIndexInSheet);
        long endCreateRow = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalCreateRowTime += endCreateRow - startCreateRow;


        long startSetValue = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols; colIndex++) {
            value = populateCell(styles, value, calendar, rowIndex, row, colIndex);
        }
        long endSetValue = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalSetValue += endSetValue - startSetValue;
        rowIndexInSheet++;
    }
    System.out.println("###@@@ Elapsed average create row " + (totalCreateRowTime / rows) + " milli seconds");
    System.out.println("###@@@ Elapsed average set value " + (totalSetValue / rows) + " milli seconds");
}
```

then I add shift row

```
private static void addContent(Workbook workBook, boolean isHType, int rows, int cols) {
    Map<String, CellStyle> styles = createStyles(workBook);

    Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);


    long startShiftRow = System.currentTimeMillis();
    sheet.shiftRows(0, sheet.getLastRowNum(), rows); // I ADD IT HERE, ONLY 1 LINE !!!

    long endShiftRow = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("###@@@ Elapsed shift rows " + (endShiftRow - startShiftRow) + " milli seconds");

    Cell headerCell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
    headerCell.setCellValue("Header text is spanned across multiple cells");
    headerCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("header"));
    sheet.addMergedRegion(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("$A$1:$F$1"));

    int sheetNo = 0;
    int rowIndexInSheet = 1;
    double value = 0;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    double totalCreateRowTime = 0;
    double totalSetValue = 0;
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++) {
        if (isHType && sheetNo != rowIndex / 0x10000) {
            sheet = workBook.createSheet("Spillover from sheet " + (++sheetNo));
            headerCell.setCellValue("Header text is spanned across multiple cells");
            headerCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("header"));
            sheet.addMergedRegion(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("$A$1:$F$1"));
            rowIndexInSheet = 1;
        }
        long startCreateRow = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIndexInSheet);
        long endCreateRow = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalCreateRowTime += endCreateRow - startCreateRow;


        long startSetValue = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols; colIndex++) {
            value = populateCell(styles, value, calendar, rowIndex, row, colIndex);
        }
        long endSetValue = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalSetValue += endSetValue - startSetValue;
        rowIndexInSheet++;
    }
    System.out.println("###@@@ Elapsed average create row " + (totalCreateRowTime / rows) + " milli seconds");
    System.out.println("###@@@ Elapsed average set value " + (totalSetValue / rows) + " milli seconds");
}
```

The log result is like this

```
-- before add shift row --
###@@@ Elapsed shift rows 0 milli seconds
###@@@ Elapsed average create row 0.00442 milli seconds
###@@@ Elapsed average set value 0.19238 milli seconds
###@@@ Elapsed done 14224 milli seconds

-- after add shift row --
###@@@ Elapsed shift rows 139 milli seconds
###@@@ Elapsed average create row 2.93634 milli seconds
###@@@ Elapsed average set value 0.21966 milli seconds
###@@@ Elapsed done 165080 milli seconds
```

The slowness is of course not from the shiftRow itself, as it only consumes 139 milliseconds. But the time used for sheet.createRow() after sheet.shiftRow() increased for more than 500 times from 0.0044 milliseconds to 2.9 milliseconds. And considered I need to write about 150,000 rows into xlsx files, it will take an unacceptable time to process.

Any other code, you can look conveniently at https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/SSPerformanceTest.java or ask me directly.

Do you know why it happens that sheet.createRow() becomes very slow after calling sheet.shiftRow()? Is there something I do wrong or is there any work around for this? Thanks in advance.

=============================================================

EDIT 1

After a little more investigation, replacing sheet.shiftRow(); with

```
sheet.createRow(50005);
```

is enough to make the whole thing slow.

Answer (score 0):

After some thoughts and experimentation, I found the cause of the problem and the workaround.

**Cause**

When I shift the row to 50000, it make the excel file becomes too big. And the processing of the too-big file becomes very slow, even though row 1 to 50000 is empty.

**Solution**

I copy those rows I want to shift to a temp sheet, then write my 50000 rows of record normally. After that I copy the footers back from the temp sheet. So now I don't have to process big excel file, just small excel file with 2 sheets.